# (Power automate)Flow licence Details

Tags: permissions, office-365, flow, power-automate

I need to check my licence details for the power automate.How can check my flow licence in office 365 portal?

Comment: Do you have any administrator permissions in your tenant?

Answer (score 0):

Just go to "My account" -> "Subscriptions"

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps:

1. Hit the below URL in browser and login with your office 365 credentials.

    `https://portal.office.com/account/`
2. Click on **Subscriptions** from left side navigation OR **View subscriptions** under **Subscriptions** section on webpage.
3. Here you will be able to see all the licenses currently assigned to you and your unique ID.

Comment: Hi Akshay, have you tried this solution? Is it working for you??